# Pop up new frame (with only one window and frame) to show specific buffers

Tags: spacemacs, buffers, frames, display-buffer-alist

I'm trying to add functionality to my spacemacs config. I want to show all`Alchemist` buffers in another frame. For example *Alchemist Test Report* or *Alchemist Mix*. So when I use `M-RET t b`, spacemacs should open a new frame if it does not already exist.

I have this in my config right now:

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             `(,(rx bos "*alchemist*" eos)
                (display-buffer-reuse-window
                   display-buffer-pop-up-frame)
               (reusable-frames     . visible)
                 ))
```

It works, but only partially. If I have more than one buffer opened in the current frame, the new frame is opened with the Alchemist buffer, but with other buffers too (Neotree for example).

The other problem is that some Alchemist frames, like those with `mix` or `iex`, are not using the Alchemist frame already opened, and they are opening a new frame.

In resume, and to simplify, I want to have one frame at the same time, with only one buffer and one window with Alchemist stuff.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Here is a link to a complex example of how to target a new or specific existing frame with a certain buffer, either file-visiting or non-file-visiting, entitled "**How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame**":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  Rather than targeting the largest window in the existing frame, you could delete those existing windows and have only one window for your new buffer if you so choose; e.g., once the frame has been selected programmatically, just call `delete-other-windows`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple way to make Emacs show certain buffers in their own frame, by default.  (And that frame will be reused when you refer to its buffer.)

Customize option **`special-display-buffer-names`** or option **`special-display-regexps`** to reflect the names of the buffers you want to display in their own frames.

For example, if all Alchemist buffers start with `Alchemist`, and no other buffers do, then this is all you need:

```
(add-to-list 'special-display-regexps "\\`Alchemist ")
```

or even:

```
(setq special-display-regexps  '("\\`Alchemist "))
```

Option `special-display-regexps` is just a list of regexps that are matched against buffer names.  Option `special-display-buffer-names` is just a list of buffer names.  `C-h f special-display-buffer-names` says this:

> ***`special-display-buffer-names`** is a variable defined in `window.el`.
>   Its value is shown below.
>
> This variable is obsolete since 24.3;
>     use `display-buffer-alist` instead.
>     This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> List of names of buffers that should be displayed specially.
>
> Displaying a buffer with `display-buffer` or `pop-to-buffer`, if
>   its name is in this list, displays the buffer in a way specified
>   by `special-display-function`.  `special-display-popup-frame`
>   (the default for `special-display-function`) usually displays
>   the buffer in a separate frame made with the parameters specified
>   by `special-display-frame-alist`.  If `special-display-function`
>   has been set to some other function, that function is called with
>   the buffer as first, and `nil` as second argument.
>
> Alternatively, an element of this list can be specified as
>   `(BUFFER-NAME FRAME-PARAMETERS)`, where `BUFFER-NAME` is a buffer
>   name and `FRAME-PARAMETERS` an alist of `(PARAMETER . VALUE)` pairs.
>   `special-display-popup-frame` will interpret such pairs as frame
>   parameters when it creates a special frame, overriding the
>   corresponding values from `special-display-frame-alist`.
>
> As a special case, if `FRAME-PARAMETERS` contains `(same-window . t)`
>   `special-display-popup-frame` displays that buffer in the
>   selected window.  If `FRAME-PARAMETERS` contains `(same-frame . t)`,
>   it displays that buffer in a window on the selected frame.
>
> If `special-display-function` specifies some other function than
>   `special-display-popup-frame`, that function is called with the
>   buffer named `BUFFER-NAME` as first, and `FRAME-PARAMETERS` as second
>   argument.
>
> Finally, an element of this list can be also specified as
>   `(BUFFER-NAME FUNCTION OTHER-ARGS)`.  In that case,
>   `special-display-popup-frame` will call `FUNCTION` with the buffer
>   named `BUFFER-NAME` as first argument, and `OTHER-ARGS` as the
>   second.
>
> Any alternative function specified here is responsible for
>   setting up the quit-restore parameter of the window used.
>
> If this variable appears "not to work", because you added a
>   name to it but the corresponding buffer is displayed in the
>   selected window, look at the values of `same-window-buffer-names`
>   and `same-window-regexps`.  Those variables take precedence over
>   this one.
>
> See also `special-display-regexps`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

---

Alternatively, you can use option `display-buffer-alist`.

Emacs claims that the `special-display-*` variables are obsolete, but they work just fine.  They should never have been deprecated, IMO.  That was done when the `display-buffer-alist` monster was created.  The idea was perhaps that the `special-display-*` options made it too easy to do such a simple thing. ;-)

It is good that `display-buffer-alist` was created.  It is not good (IMHO) for Emacs to consider `special-display-*` to be deprecated.

Comment: Hear hear on your op-ed below the box.